# Android 0nTouch event problem [Swipe DOWN and UP]

Tags: android

im having an application which needs  onTouch swipe events like in Iphone. they are

1. Swipe Up.
2. Swipe Down.
3. Swipe Left.
4. Swipe Right.

i implemented onTouch event as following . and i got Swipe Left and Right actions correctly.but which is the correct way to implement the swipe Down and Up actions.

MYCODE:

```
    float downXValue,downYValue;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg1) {

         // Get the action that was done on this touch event
        switch (arg1.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {
                // store the X value when the user's finger was pressed down
                downXValue = arg1.getX();
                downYValue = arg1.getY();
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {
                // Get the X value when the user released his/her finger
                float currentX = arg1.getX();   
                float currentY=arg1.getY();

                // going backwards: pushing stuff to the right
                if (downXValue < currentX)
                {
                    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Right");
                }

                // going forwards: pushing stuff to the left
                if (downXValue > currentX)
                {

                    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Left");
                }
                break;
            }
        }

         //GestureListener is called here... 

        //return gestures.onTouchEvent(event);


        return true;
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about...

```
if (downYValue < currentY)
{
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Down");
}
```

Are you sure you wrote the code above?

**Edit**

OK, I believe you. What you have to do is basically:

```
double sizeInX = Math.abs(downXValue - currentX);
double sizeInY = Math.abs(downYValue - currentY);
if( sizeInX > sizeInY ){
   // you better swipe horizontally
} else {
   // you better swipe vertically
}
```

Comment: Hi crisitain thanks for the reply i have already added that but it will result with Swipe Down And Swipe Right or Left Actions. that it will result in 2 actions.

Answer (score 2):

This is a listener I wrote some time ago, that handles both up an down swypes. Theres a `float oldPosition` variable that I used to track the touch position. There is some unneeded code in there but you'll get the idea:

```
    LinearLayout tableM = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.tableM);
    tableM.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener () {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                oldPosition = event.getY();
                return true;
            } else
            if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                if (event.getY() < oldPosition) {
                    tableIndexM++;
                    if (tableIndexM > (minsecs.length - 3)) {
                        tableIndexM = 0;
                    }
                    fillTable (rowM0, rowM1, rowM2, minsecs, tableIndexM);
                }
                else if (event.getY() > oldPosition) {
                    tableIndexM--;
                    if (tableIndexM < 0) {
                        tableIndexM = minsecs.length - 3;
                    }
                    fillTable (rowM0, rowM1, rowM2, minsecs, tableIndexM);
                }
                oldPosition = event.getY();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: hi Aleadam thanks for the answer.. my problem is i want all 4 Events SWIPE UP ,DOWN, LEFT RIGHT. if i use ur answer it will result in 2 actions . that is up/down and left/right.

Comment: I understand that, but you can still evaluate the mininum traveled position/time to any direction in each `ACTION_MOVE` event and act accordingly, i.e., a bunch of `if (event.getX > oldXPos)` ... `if (event.getY() > oldYPos)`, etc, the first one to reach your threshold fires the action and resets all the markers.

Comment: @user I did not get your comment to Cristian: "that it will result in 2 actions". Did you add a `return true;` statement after `Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Down");`? And how do you set the thresholds? Not every tiny move should be a swype. I would at least do something like `if (downYValue < (currentY+50))`

Comment: No Aleadam the problem was i was not giving any timing constraints there . that was the problem . now i got the solution.