# Android : How can I Swipe Up and Swipe Down in touchListener event of Imageview?

Tags: android, swipe, touch-event

I have application in which I need onTouch swipe Up and Down event.
I have implemented onTouch event in application but I have not any idea related to Swipe Up and Swipe Down
Does anybody have a code that how can I do this?

```
final ImageView imageView = listOfImageView.get(i);
            imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener () {
                private float oldPosition;
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        this.oldPosition = event.getY();

                    }
                 }
            });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698839/android-0ntouch-event-problem-swipe-down-and-up

Search before replicating..

Comment: Should work... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures